# how to apply a function over dataframe colum in month wise and show it in columns month wise?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

i have some input data like below in a data frame .

```
id priority owner goal changed_time delta_time 
1   P1      bob    40   2016-11-02   20
2   P2      bob    20   2016-11-02   10
3   P3      bob    30   2016-11-02   50
4   P1      alice  20   2016-10-02   70
5   P1      bob    40   2016-10-02   05
6   P1      bob    40   2016-10-02   24
7   P3      alice  40   2016-09-02   34
8   P1      bob    40   2016-09-02   20
9   P2      ross   40   2016-09-02   10
10  P1      bob    40   2016-11-02   20
11  P2      sec    40   2016-09-02   34
12  P3      bob    30   2016-11-02   90
```

i want output like below. left side grouping i am doing by

```
df[['owner','priority','Goal','Delta_time']].groupby(['productowner','priority']).mean()
```

but i want output like below .

```
                 (Average of delta_time in monthly basis)
owner priority goal  2016-11  2016-10  2016-09

bob    p1      40     
       p2      20
       p3      30
alice  p1      20
       p3      40
ross   p2      40
sec    p2      40
```

so how to apply mean function over delta_time column which'll be on monthly range depending on changed_time column and should be shown in column wise like above table. I am already getting in left side by grouping by using

```
df[['owner','priority','Goal','Delta_time']].groupby([df.statusChangedtime.dt.month,'owner','priority']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done something like this:

```
df.groupby(['priority','owner',pd.PeriodIndex(data=df.changed_time, freq='M')]]).mean().unstack()
```

[image: One groupby]

---

To get your required format, I think you need to do two separate groupby then concat:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['priority','owner'])['goal'].mean()
# You can also do: pd.DatetimeIndex(data=df.changed_time).month
df2 = df.groupby(['priority','owner',pd.PeriodIndex(data=df.changed_time, freq='M')])['delta_time'].mean().unstack()
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

[image: Two groupbys]

Comment: Perfect !! ..Thanks a lot @Julien

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question what language the answer should be in since there are multiple language tags.  In general questions need to be focused and should deal in only one language.  This is likely why a number of people have downvoted the question.

At any rate, in case you wanted the answer in R here are some alternatives:

**1) reshape2** Add a year/month column (`"time"`) and reshape from long to wide using `mean`:

```
library(reshape2)

df2 <- transform(df, time = substr(changed_time, 1, 7))
dcast(df2, owner + priority + goal ~ time, mean, value.var = "delta_time", fill = NA_real_)
```

giving:

```
  owner priority goal 2016-09 2016-10 2016-11
1 alice       P1   20      NA    70.0      NA
2 alice       P3   40      34      NA      NA
3   bob       P1   40      20    14.5      20
4   bob       P2   20      NA      NA      10
5   bob       P3   30      NA      NA      70
6  ross       P2   40      10      NA      NA
7   sec       P2   40      34      NA      NA
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr**  Add the month/year `"time"` column, and compute the average delta_time by `owner`, `priority`, `goal` and `time`.  Finally convert from long to wide and sort.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(time = substr(changed_time, 1, 7)) %>%
   group_by(owner, priority, goal, time) %>%
   summarize(delta_time = mean(delta_time)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(time, delta_time) %>%
   arrange(owner, priority)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
   owner priority  goal 2016-09 2016-10 2016-11
  <fctr>   <fctr> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  alice       P1    20      NA    70.0      NA
2  alice       P3    40      34      NA      NA
3    bob       P1    40      20    14.5      20
4    bob       P2    20      NA      NA      10
5    bob       P3    30      NA      NA      70
6   ross       P2    40      10      NA      NA
7    sec       P2    40      34      NA      NA
```

**3) no packages** Add a year/month column (`"time"`), calculate the means using `aggregate` and then convert from long to wide using `reshape` and sort:

```
df2 <- transform(df, time = substr(changed_time, 1, 7))
ag <- aggregate(delta_time ~ owner + priority + goal + time, df2, mean) 
nms <- unique(as.character(sort(ag$time)))
r <- reshape(ag, dir = "wide", idvar = c("owner", "priority", "goal"), varying = list(nms))
o <- order(r$owner, r$priority)
r[o, ]
```

giving:

```
  owner priority goal 2016-09 2016-10 2016-11
5 alice       P1   20      NA    70.0      NA
4 alice       P3   40      34      NA      NA
1   bob       P1   40      20    14.5      20
7   bob       P2   20      NA      NA      10
8   bob       P3   30      NA      NA      70
2  ross       P2   40      10      NA      NA
3   sec       P2   40      34      NA      NA
```

**Note:**  The input data frame `df` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "id priority owner goal changed_time delta_time 
1   P1      bob    40   2016-11-02   20
2   P2      bob    20   2016-11-02   10
3   P3      bob    30   2016-11-02   50
4   P1      alice  20   2016-10-02   70
5   P1      bob    40   2016-10-02   05
6   P1      bob    40   2016-10-02   24
7   P3      alice  40   2016-09-02   34
8   P1      bob    40   2016-09-02   20
9   P2      ross   40   2016-09-02   10
10  P1      bob    40   2016-11-02   20
11  P2      sec    40   2016-09-02   34
12  P3      bob    30   2016-11-02   90"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: yeaa!! i wanted the answer in both python and R also..That's why i tagged R in the question ...Thanks @Grothendieck for the answer in R !!